# Updating video drivers for Dell XPS 17 (L702x)

Tags: nvidia-geforce, dell-xps, optimus, display-driver

For my other laptops (Dell or otherwise), I'd regularly check NVidia's site for updates on the video card drivers and download and install them when needed.

I'm confused about how I should update my NVidia driver for my Dell XPS 17 (L702x). It has this Optimus system, which seamlessly switches from integrated Intel video card to NVidia card. I've tried installing the latest drivers for that NVidia card (it's a GT 555M), downloaded from the NVidia site,  but the NVidia installer sais something like "there's no card to install these for". I've checked the Dell Support, and the NVidia video card section there has very old drivers (which I already have).  I've also checked NVidia's site for "NVidia optimus drivers" and found some, but those are old as well (sais it's from 2010).

So please, if anyone has this laptop (or another with a similar NVidia optimus system), can you please tell me how I can install the very latest drivers for my NVidia card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the link listed below and chose the appropriate options. The drivers appear to have been updated this year and they should work assuming the file download hasn't been corrupted. Otherwise you may have conflicting or corrupted drivers installed on your computer which you can attempt to fix by trying to uninstall the current drivers and reinstall them again.

http://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I've noticed that too, the new driver bundle they have (version 3.x.x) works ok. It has a nice option to remove all old drivers (it removed Optimus, Video and Audio drivers) and install the new ones. Tried that, worked fine.